# Can "in front of" be followed by an abstract concept?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-request

> Above, the square *in front of* the entrance to the bank's headquarters in Siena.

Reading several occurrences of "in front of" in The New York Times, I observed that this phrase is always followed by a material object: "the entrance", like in the case above; but there are other words like "a subway train", "a cafe", "him" and so on.

I did not observe, on the contrary, occurrences of "in front of" followed by an abstract object or entity. As I'm Italian, I consider this circumstance notable because we often use "in front of" followed by abstract entities: "in front of a miracle I would be shocked" and  "in front of such arrogance I recede" are only two examples illustrating how "in front of" works in Italian.

So, question is: Can we use "in front of" followed by an abstract thing? If not, what phrase should we use to express a similar concept?

Comment: No. "I was standing **in front of a miracle** when all of a sudden Joan of Arc started whispering in my ear that I'd better go save France or stand **in front of a firing squad**". The first instance of **in front of** is not idiomatic English, but the second is.

Comment: *In front of* is usually reserved for actual physical location. For  your purposes, in addition to @WendiKidd's "in the face of* and *faced with*, there are also *confronting*, *confronted with* and simply *before*.

Comment: To piggy-back on what others said, we **can** use "in front of" with something abstract, but, when we do, the abstract thing usually **precedes** the "in front of" (e.g., _I had a long and arduous journey in front of me; I had a tough problem in front of me; There it was – a miracle, right in front of me._)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The phrase we use here in English is "[in the face of](http://www.usingenglish.com/reference/idioms/in+the+face+of.html)".

> I laugh in the face of danger! (-The Lion King)

This also works with the examples you suggested, and many many more. So this would be the equivalent English expression!

---

Hmm, actually upon further reflection, more appropriate might be "when faced with".  I can't find a link to a dictionary that defines it, but this has the meaning of *when presented with*.  To transform one of your examples:

> When faced with such arrogance, I recede.

This might be the more appropriate term depending on your circumstances, because "in the face of" actually has a more specific meaning; it means *when presented with [x], I do [y] anyway* (or *despite [x]*). So depending upon context, one might be more appropriate than the other.

To determine the difference between the two, let's take two contrasting examples.

> When faced with the prospect of life in prison, the suspect ran.

This makes sense: you're faced with something bad, so you try to escape it.  You're making a logical choice *when faced with* something.

> I laugh in the face of danger!

I know this repeats my earlier example, but it's the best way to explain. Danger is a bad thing; laughter probably isn't the first logical response. But since we used *in the face of*, we're laughing *despite* the danger; though we are faced with danger, we laugh anyway. That seems to be the difference between the two expressions.

Comment: +Many When you laugh **in the face of** danger, it is (a personified) danger who has the face: you are offering 'him' a personal affront. When you are **faced with** danger, it is your face which is in play; danger is, as we now say, "in your face". In the first, you **confront** danger; in the second danger **confronts** you. *Front*, by the way, is from a Latin word which originally meant *forehead* and was extended to the *face* and thence to the part of anything which *faces* you; historically it has in the past been used in all these senses in English. It's all one metaphor!